# "Il rend fiers ses parents" ou "il rend fier ses parents" ?

Tags: orthographe

Est-ce qu'on écrit "il rend **fiers** ses parents" ou "il rend **fier** ses parents" ?

Je suis presque sûr qu'on accorde "fier" mais je ne sais pas pourquoi et je trouve plein de contre-exemples.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Aucune occurrence de *rend fier ses* dans Google books et seulement six trouvées sur le web par Google. *Plein* de contre-exemples est très exagéré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il faut l'accord même lorsque la place de l'adjectif est avant le nom.

([Avez-vous le sens du client ?: Adoptez le point de vue du](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Avez_vous_le_sens_du_client/fd7SDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rend+fiers%22&pg=PP171&printsec=frontcover) ) L'amour de la marque rapproche et rend fiers les clients et les collaborateurs, heureux d'appartenir à une communauté

([Le monde différent de Vincent](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_monde_diff%C3%A9rent_de_Vincent/aGelEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rend+fiers%22&pg=PT75&printsec=frontcover)) Il symbolise le lien entre tous les villages et rend fiers les villageois.

([Le coeur des Québécois : L'évolution du Québec de 1976 à aujourd'hui](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_coeur_des_Qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_L_%C3%A9volution_du/1cwoEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rend+fiers%22&pg=PA191&printsec=frontcover))  De façon plus positive, nous avons également souhaité connaître ce qui rend fiers les Québécois d'aujourd'hui.

([La langue maltaise: études syntaxiques d'un dialecte arabe](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_langue_maltaise/_HIZBgs7iQEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rend+fi%C3%A8re%22&pg=PA363&printsec=frontcover) ) Le contexte est suffisamment clair en effet c'est d'avoir 90 ans qui rend fière la vieille femme et non pas un trait de caractère particulier